# How to view the ConnectionString value of Flat File Connection while debugging?

Tags: ssis, connection-string, flat-file

There seem to be 2 ways to set up the connection string in `FlatFile` connection properties:

1. Using `ConnectionString` property
2. Using `ConnectionString` expression

Which one will be used? Is there any way to see this value during the debug, or to print it out (is adding a new task, 'print in a file', a reasonable workaround)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with everything in SSIS, an expression is used to overwrite the value of a property.

Answer (score 1):

***`ConnectionString`*** property will be used to evaluate the path of the flat file on the *Flat File Connection Manager*. As [@Dominic Goulet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452792/dominic-goulet) stated, ***`Expressions`*** allows you to override any property during runtime.

The value of the *`ConnectionString`* will be displayed on the *`Progress`* / *`Execution Results`* tab on the *Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)* when you execute the package. *`Progress`* is the tab name during run-time, which is then changed to *`Execution Results`* once you stop debugging in BIDS.

If you enable package logging and capture *`OnInformation`* event messages, you will see the same information in the log data.

#### ConnectionString value of flat file connection emitted during Information event.

[image: ConnectionString]